# Wordpress: Change sitewide category order?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to change the order in which my posts are displayed on my category pages.

Let me know if you know how it's done. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code before the start of the 'loop' to change the ordering of your posts:

```
<?php
$posts = query_posts($query_string .  '&orderby=title&order=asc');
// here comes The Loop!
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

This will modify the loop to order posts by the title in ascending order. You can then just modify this orderby= and order= to change between the different fields and whether to order in ascending or descending order.